# Check for command line input and abort setup with inno setup

Tags: c#, windows, inno-setup, pascal

I'm trying to make a windows installer using Inno Setup which calls an external command line application. If the external application fails I want Inno Setup to either abort with a message saying that the app should be uninstalled and installed again. Or even better: rollback the installation.

The way I was planning to do this (let me know if you got better ideas) was to write to a log file from the external application if any errors occurs. Inno setup should after calling the external app check if the log file contains the string "ok" or not.

I call my external app like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\exec.exe"; Parameters: "{app}"; AfterInstall: checkLog
```

And I was planning to have something like:

```
[Code]
procedure checkLog;
begin

end;
```

So my question is: How do i retrieve the string from the log and check whether it contains the string "ok" or not? (The path can be a argument to the procedure) And how do I abort the installation with a message or rollback the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
function LoadStringFromFile(const FileName: String; var S: AnsiString): Boolean;
```

and verify if the string read from the file has `OK`

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know anything about aborting/rolling back the installation?